# Deploy JavaFX11 for Windows on Linux Server With Gradle

Tags: java, linux, windows, gradle, javafx

I would like to migrate an JavaFX 8 project into an JavaFX 11 project and had to fight with some deployment-issues.

After hours spend I can deploy and run my JavaFX11-application as a fatjar successfully on my windows pc.

But now I have to deploy the application on a linux-server, but it get used on windows pc.

Therefore the errors are coming back..
I have noticed that the same jar when build on linux contains some .so-files and when build on windows some .dll-files.

After reading some similar other questions i assume that this is the problem.
My Project includes gradle dependencies for JavaFX11, which are plattform-dependent and automatically downloaded as linux version due to the current OS of the build-server.

**Is there a way to force gradle to load windows-dependencies for JavaFX11 even when builded on an linux server?**

BTW this is my gradle.build:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.17.2'
}

dependencies{ 
/* Some dependencies..*/
}
javafx {
    version = "11"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml'] 
}
jlink {
    launcher {
        name = 'exe_name'
    }
}
mainClassName = 'test.Launcher'
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
            'Main-Class': 'test.Launcher'
        )
    }
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

***Greetings***

Comment: The easiest solution is to install a distribution of Java on the server that includes JavaFX. Two options are _Liberica_ and _Zulu Community_. Another option is to install JavaFX on your sever manually. Otherwise, the JavaFX plugin simply adds a `win`, `linux`, or `mac` classifier to the JavaFX dependencies based on the operating system the Gradle build is running on. You can manually specify these classifiers, but note that Gradle does not pull in transitive dependencies when you specify a classifier. That all being said, why do you need JavaFX, a _client_ technology, on the _server_ side?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I don't need JavaFX on the server side. My Application is just being build on a linux-server, for external reasons. It finds its use of course as client technology on my teammates computers. I will try to manually specify the classifiers.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question (I thought you were building on Windows and attempting to deploy to a Linux server). But yes, you can do something like `org.openjfx:javafx-base:$fxVersion:linux` (in the `dependencies` block) to pull in the Linux-specific JavaFX JAR file. As I mentioned though, you'll have to explicitly add each individual JavaFX module since transitive resolution does not occur when a classifier is specified. This approach is, as far as I know, only viable for creating fat/uber JAR files and won't work with `jlink` and/or `jpackage`.

Comment: By the way, since you're creating a fat/uber JAR file you might want to consider looking into the [Gradle Shadow Plugin](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/).

Comment: Thank you. Reading your comments pointed me into the right direction.